# Convert varchar to char ? how to fix error

Tags: c#, sql

I get this error below when I want to convert DRMKOD to char ?

[ varchar(1) coloumn ] is the type of "DRMKOD" column  on sql table.

> String must be exactly one character
>   long.    at
>   System.Convert.ToChar(String value,
>   IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToChar(IFormatProvider
>   provider)    at
>   System.Convert.ToChar(Object value)

```
 entity.DrmKod = Convert.ToChar(dt.Rows[i]["DRMKOD"]);
```

---

```
 public char DrmKod
        {
            get { return _DrmKod; }
            set { _DrmKod = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value that is dt.Rows[i]["DRMKOD"]? I can only think that it is something that is either empty or null.

Comment: SELECT 
  [DRMKOD]
  FROM  TABLE_PAYMENTS (nolock)
  where ISNULL([DRMKOD],'') =''   -- has returned 6 empty or null rows..

Comment: So this is going to return DRMKOD where it is '' (<--- empty string), that would give you the error for sure since it is not ' '. (<--- whitespace)

Answer (score 3):

The two types are not compatible. `varchar` is a string, `char` is a single character.

Convert the result to a string, and then get the first character using `str[0]` (assuming the string even has any characters and is not null!).

Comment: Load the result into a string and examine it? It's probably an empty string. And why the heck are you using VARCHAR if it's always 1 character?

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR(1) implies that it can be NULL or String.Empty.

```
if (dt.Rows[i].IsNull("DRMKOD") || (dt.Rows[i]["DRMKOD"] == String.Empty))
    entity.DrmKod = ' '
else
    entity.DrmKod = Convert.ToChar(dt.Rows[i]["DRMKOD"]);
```